# Sorting in java reverseOrder

Tags: java, string, sorting

I have:

```
String[] subdivisions = {"K1","K1\\SK1","K2","K2\\SK1\\SSK1"};
```

I sorted:

```
Arrays.stream(subdivisions).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I get:

```
K2\SK1\SSK1
K2
K1\SK1
K1
```

But I need to sort this way:

```
K2
K2\SK1\SSK1
K1
K1\SK1
```

How can I change sort condition?
How do I write the sort correctly?

Comment: By writing your own comparator that puts "A\B" after "A"?

Comment: What if the elements are not in that order? do you expect always that result?

Comment: @YCF_L It's a *sort*, the original order is immaterial. `reverseOrder()` is not a reversing operation, it's a descending natural-order sort.

Comment: @YCF_L yes .I need to first go where the length is less than the next element. And in reverse order

Comment: @YCF_L I understood it, just cited as an example.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of a custom `Comparator` method for sorting the way you want:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] subdivisions = {"K1","K1\\SK1","K2","K2\\SK1\\SSK1"};

        Arrays.stream(subdivisions).sorted(Test::compare).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    private static int compare(String a, String b) {
        if (a.length() < b.length() && b.startsWith(a))
            return -1; // a is prefix of b, so sort a first
        if (b.length() < a.length() && a.startsWith(b))
            return 1; // b is prefix of a, so sort b first
        return b.compareTo(a); // descending
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
K2
K2\SK1\SSK1
K1
K1\SK1
```

Answer (score 0):

*…here is a lambda expression for the required sorting:*

```
Arrays.stream( subdivisions ).sorted(
    (new Comparator<String>() {
      @Override
      public int compare( String s1, String s2 ) {
        int len = Math.min( s1.length(), s2.length() );
        return( s2.substring( 0, len ).compareTo( s1.substring( 0, len ) ) );
      } }).thenComparing( String::length ) ).forEach( System.out::println );
```